# Overriding and extending a field to update a View using AJAX

Tags: views, nodes, 8, entities, ajax

I have a series of nodes that are rendered using a view.

In these individual nodes - as part of the display mode I have a field that links the node to a taxonomy. This is rendered as a label (linked to an entity reference) and can be overriden using the field *field-taxonomy-term-link.html.twig*

Note the view has an exposed filter that allows users to filter the view by the mentioned taxonomy above.

The question is:

How can I alter my *field-taxonomy-term-link.html.twig* template to update the view using AJAX when I click on my field link, instead of forcing a page referesh as i'm doing at the moment using a query parameter in the url / contextual filter / $_GET method.

As it stands my *field-taxonomy-term-link.html.twig* contains:

```
{#
/**
 * @file
 * Theme override for a field.
 *
 * To override output, copy the "field.html.twig" from the templates directory
 * to your theme's directory and customize it, just like customizing other
 * Drupal templates such as page.html.twig or node.html.twig.
 *
 * Instead of overriding the theming for all fields, you can also just override
 * theming for a subset of fields using
 * @link themeable Theme hook suggestions. @endlink For example,
 * here are some theme hook suggestions that can be used for a field_foo field
 * on an article node type:
 * - field--node--field-foo--article.html.twig
 * - field--node--field-foo.html.twig
 * - field--node--article.html.twig
 * - field--field-foo.html.twig
 * - field--text-with-summary.html.twig
 * - field.html.twig
 *
 * Available variables:
 * - attributes: HTML attributes for the containing element.
 * - label_hidden: Whether to show the field label or not.
 * - title_attributes: HTML attributes for the title.
 * - label: The label for the field.
 * - multiple: TRUE if a field can contain multiple items.
 * - items: List of all the field items. Each item contains:
 *   - attributes: List of HTML attributes for each item.
 *   - content: The field item's content.
 * - entity_type: The entity type to which the field belongs.
 * - field_name: The name of the field.
 * - field_type: The type of the field.
 * - label_display: The display settings for the label.
 *
 * @ingroup templates
 *
 * @see template_preprocess_field()
 */
#}

    {%
      set classes = [
        'field',
        'field--name-' ~ field_name|clean_class,
        'field--type-' ~ field_type|clean_class,
        'field--label-' ~ label_display,
      ]
    %}
    {%
      set title_classes = [
        'field--label',
        label_display == 'visually_hidden' ? 'sr-only',
      ]
    %}

    {% set taxonomy_term_link = '/my-view-url?link=123' %}

    {% if label_hidden %}
      {% if multiple %}
        <div{{ attributes.addClass(classes, 'field--items') }}>
          {% for item in items %}
            <div{{ item.attributes.addClass('field--item') }}><a href="{{ taxonomy_term_link }}" hreflang="en">{{ item.content['#title'] }}</a></div>
          {% endfor %}
        </div>
      {% else %}
        {% for item in items %}
          <div{{ attributes.addClass(classes, 'field--item') }}><a href="{{ taxonomy_term_link }}" hreflang="en">{{ item.content['#title'] }}</a></div>
        {% endfor %}
      {% endif %}
    {% else %}
      <div{{ attributes.addClass(classes) }}>
        <div{{ title_attributes.addClass(title_classes) }}>{{ label }}</div>
        {% if multiple %}
          <div class="field__items">
        {% endif %}
        {% for item in items %}
          <div{{ item.attributes.addClass('field--item') }}><a href="{{ taxonomy_term_link }}" hreflang="en">{{ item.content['#title'] }}</a></div>
        {% endfor %}
        {% if multiple %}
          </div>
        {% endif %}
      </div>
    {% endif %}
```

Can anyone offer a solution that integrates with the AJAX in the view.. do I have to use the Drupal 8 JS API to manipulate the view?